# Find all nodes in directed graph from starting node that complete a loop

Tags: directed-graphs

Suppose I have a directed graph, where one of the nodes is selected to be the "initial" node. **What algorithms should I consider using** to to find all the nodes that

- have a path from the initial node to itself
- have a path from itself to the initial node

For example, in the below graph with node A as the initial node, I would like the algorithm to only return the green nodes, as they are the only nodes that have a complete path to and from node A.

[image: image of graph]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the BFS algorithm to find the path from the source node to any other node (and it even produces the shortest path).

For the converse, run the BFS on the transposed graph (swap the direction of each edge).

In your example, what you found is the strongly connected component that the initial source node resids in. There are plenty of fast algorithms to compute the set of all strongly connected components in the graph, if you are interested.